# WL terminology: evaluate, call, invoke, use, etc

Tags: core-language, language-design

A WL (Mma) program is a sequence of expressions to be evaluated, which generally involves applying commands and functions to actual arguments.  What is the accepted terminology for what I think of as a function call?  (Is this somehow misusing concepts from other languages?)  What is the name for the square brackets used to make such a call, which I would be inclined to call *call brackets*?

The documents seem most often to say we *use* a command.  But I hate this, since we also "use" a command if we pass it as an argument (e.g., to map it over a list).  Is the documentation terminology just being folksy, or is it meant to be technical?  If the latter, what is the terminology for distinguishing these different kinds of uses?

And btw, does the word "command" always imply a WL builtin, while "function" implies it is a user created callable?  (Is there a WL term for "callable"? And finally, what is the test for callability, since CallableQ does not exist?)

Comment: For any expression `expr`, `expr[args]` is also an expression that will evaluate to something (possibly to itself). It's true even for basic atomic expressions e.g. `5[a, b]` is a valid expression, I don't think I've seen any practical use for such expressions, but there's nothing "incorrect" about them. In that sense everything is "callable". On the practical side, I can see a need to answer following question. Given expression `expr` and arguments `args` of certain "type" will result of evaluation of `expr[args]` be of some other "type"?

Comment: Depending on answer to this question one could, choose different branch of some algorithm, perform some code optimizations, or check code validity i.e. all benefits of static type checking. *Mathematica*, in general, does not provide such functionality out of the box, but for certain specific use cases one can introduce some forms of specialized type systems. Compilation functionality has a type system, datasets introduced type system for queries.

Comment: Here is a discussion of *M* as a *term-rewriting system* by one of the developers (R. Maeder): http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/183/. Related [(SO/4430998)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430998/mathematica-what-is-symbolic-programming), [(119933)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119933/why-did-the-mathematica-language-choose-term-rewriting-instead-of-the-lambda-cal). Another article by Maeder, which I can't find a copy of: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/3255/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that in Mathematica, symbols, expressions, evaluation and substitution rules are fundamental terms.

One writes an expression, sends it to the Mathematica kernel, kernel evaluates the expression (i.e. applies all relevant substitution rules) and returns the resulting expression.

For example, one may write `f1[x,y]`. This is just an expression with head `f1` and two parts `x` and `y`,
where `f1`, `x`, and `y` are all symbols. Square brackets are just a notation to distinguish
parts from the head. If there is only one part one may use `f1@x` instead of the brackets.

One may define a substitution rule for symbol `f1`. For example:

```
f1[_Real, _Real]:=0
```

This instructs kernel to replace any sub-expression with head `f1` and two real parts with `0` (another expression).
However, if kernel encounters `f1[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]` or `f1[a,b]`, no substitution will be made.

Very formally `f1` is a symbol, which might induce a substitution when encountered as a head of subexpression during evaluation.

For simplicity, one calls `f1` a function.

When `f1[1.0, 1.0]` gets substituted by `0` during evaluation, one may say that this is a function call.

In my experience, the term "function" is usually used for symbols which evaluate to numeric expression (i.e. `Sin`),
while the term "command" is used for symbols which evaluate to some other expressions (i.e. `Plot` is substituted by `Graphics`)

There is no `Callable` in Mathematica, but there is an internal (undocumented) function to check if given expression might cause a substitution when used as a head:

```
System`Private`MightEvaluateWhenAppliedQ[f1]
```

> True

This function can correctly identify pure functions as well:

```
System`Private`MightEvaluateWhenAppliedQ[(#) &]
```

> True

Comment: This is pretty close to the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks; I'm going to chew on it a bit.

Answer (score 7):

> A WL (Mma) program is a sequence of expressions to be evaluated, which
>   generally involves applying commands and functions to actual
>   arguments.

A program in Mathematica is a sequence of expression evaluations, period. A "function" or "command" is a replacement rule:

```
f[x_] := x
DownValues[f]
```

> `{HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x}`

Instead of `f[x_] := x; f[5]` we might just as well write `f[5] /. f[x_] :> x`. Both user-defined "functions" and "built-in functions" work in this way. Replacement rules, functions, and commands are all the same thing.

[What is the distinction between DownValues, UpValues, SubValues, and OwnValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues) shows that there are several different ways to attach replacement rules to symbols. "Functions" and "commands" is what we would say about symbols with `DownValues` (and more rarely up values and `SubValues`; symbols with `SubValues` would more commonly be referred to as operators), whereas symbols with `OwnValues` would be called variables.

I think it is justified to call `f` a function (or command) whether it appears in the context `f[5]` or `Map[f, {1,2,3]`. In both cases, `f` represents a symbol with an entry in `DownValues[f]`.

Perhaps the distinction that you are looking for is that `f[5]` evaluates to something else, whereas `f` by itself does not. `ValueQ` exists to check if this is the case. Note that `ValueQ` will also return `True` if the expression will be transformed by `OwnValues`, `UpValues`, or `SubValues`, though. Not just `DownValues`.

Comment: I don't quarrel with what you wrote, but I don't think it answers my question. One exception: you suggest that "command" and "function" are  synonyms; but that does not seem to match usage in the documentation. (I get your point about `ValueQ`, but it still diverges from my query.)  My question is  primarily about terminology, not about how WL works.
Are you saying that since this is all a matter of replacement rules, to use the notion of a function call is misguided?  Yet surely some simple term is used whether `f` is defined with `Function` (own values) or by pattern matching (down values).

Comment: @Alan `Function` is a special case. A symbol defined as a `Function` object is always called an "anonymous function". There are other special cases as well, a symbol defined as an `Association` is called an "association". These symbols take their names from the objects they evaluate to. But as for the questions, I think I did answer those: It makes no sense to separate built-in from user defined functions because they are the same. It makes no sense to distinguish between functions and commands because there aren't two separate concepts. I explained when the word "operator" is used instead.

Comment: @Alan My comment about `ValueQ` was in response to your question about whether there is a `CallableQ` – now, it is not exactly clear what you mean by "callable," but by my interpretation `ValueQ` is the most related test in Mathematica. If you could quote specific examples in the documentation where you think "function" (not in the context of "anonymous function") and "command" are not used interchangeably, that would help.

Comment: @Alan As for the question about square brackets, I did not understand it. What do you call parentheses in languages that use those instead, "call parentheses"?

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason we might call `f` an "anonymous function" if it is defined as such, is because it is a variable and that is what it holds. It's in the same sense as the following: "What is `x`?" "It's an integer", "What is `m`?" "It's a sparse array", "What is `l`?" "It's a list"  etc. "What is `f`?" "It's an anonymous function." Meaning, it holds an anonymous function.

Comment: The reason I do not think `ValueQ` offers a useful test of callability is that it cannot tell us that `f1` defined by pattern matching and `f2` defined with `Function` are both "callable".  Compare `isinstance(x, collections.Callable)` in Python.  (Of course, if we stick just with `Function`, we can check the head.)  Nevertheless, I take your point that there is something suspect about trying to say `f1` and `f2` share some feature called "callability"; this does seem to be the wrong paradigm.  So, how do WL users rephrase sentences like this:  "`f2` calls `f1` with arguments `x` and `y`"?

Comment: @Alan I think it is ok so say "`f2` calls `f1` with arguments `x` and `y`", but does that mean that `f1` is necessarily callable? In Wolfram Language, I would just take that to mean that "`f2` evaluates `f1[x,y]`". `f1[x,y]` may evaluate to something different, or it may not: either way, it's valid Mathematica code. Also, note that a symbol is not inherently "callable". It is callable and it isn't. It depends on the parameters. I'm guessing a callable in Python throws an error if it is supplied with arguments for which it has not been defined.

Comment: @Alan You say that the problem with `ValueQ` is that it does not tell top level functions (functions defined with pattern matching) apart from anonymous function. Do you mean that functions defined with pattern matching are not callable and anonymous functions are?

Comment: You have pretty much convinced me that talking about callability in WL is not very fruitful.  Shadowray pointed out `System\`Private\`MightEvaluateWhenAppliedQ`, which is essentially what I was looking for.  It will give the same answer for `f1` and `f2` (above), while `ValueQ` will not.  In this sense, we might say applicability rather than callability is the relevant concept.  (Yep, I'm a non-CS guy making up words as I go along.)  Thanks!