# How to require that a function argument be a pure function or a function-style replacement rule?

Tags: argument-patterns

I'm trying to write a function whose first argument must be another function, defined either as a pure function or a function-style replacement rule. I don't know how to specify a condition on the argument to achieve that. I know I can use `g[func_Function,…]` to require pure functions, but functions defined via replacement rules don't have a useful `Head`.

Here's an example:

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 1;
g[func_?MatchQ[#, _[___]] &, a_, b_] := func[a + b];
g[f, 1, 2]
(* g[f, 1, 2] *)
```

Checking the `Head` of `f` doesn't seem helpful:

```
Head[f] (* ==> Symbol *)
Head[f[x]] (* ==> Plus *)
```

How can I constrain the arguments to `g` such that it will accept either a pure function or a function defined with `:=`?

Comment: There's no way to do this. I think you shouldn't.  If you feel that you need a check, check that the result of applying the function is as expected.

Comment: There are countless very different looking expressions in Mathematica which can all be "called" as if they were a function. By trying to restrict your input, you will inevitably prevent the use of at least some of these.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147942/wl-terminology-evaluate-call-invoke-use-etc

Comment: @Alan, I was very hopeful when saw `System'Private'MightEvaluateWhenAppliedQ` in the page you linked to, but I could't get it to do anything. Every time I tried using it, I just got my expression back unevaluated. :(

Comment: Try ``System`Private`MightEvaluateWhenAppliedQ[f]``, then `f[x_] := x^2`, then ``System`Private`MightEvaluateWhenAppliedQ[f]`` again.

Comment: But even with this undocumented function, I maintain that trying to test if something is "a function" is not generally a good idea.  There is never a guarantee that it will evaluate: if `f[x_?NumberQ] := x^2` then neither of `f[x]` or `f[Pi]` or `f[Sqrt[2]]` will evaluate.  If `x /: g[x] = 1` then `MightEvaluateWhenAppliedQ[g]` is `False` but `g[x]` evaluates. While this is a contrived example, UpValues are really used like this in practice. This is how many of the group theory functions are implemented for groups not represented as permutation groups.

Comment: @Szabolcs I hear you, and will keep it in mind for the future. But context is everything; for what I’m doing with my Mma neophyte students, handling `f[___]:=` and pure functions is adequate.

Comment: @ibeatty Ah, they're beginners and you mean you want to prevent them putting in `x^2+1` where `#^2 + 1&` is needed. Viewed that way, it makes sense.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, and because I’m trying to teach them the good habit of restricting input types. The current assignment requires writing functions that take a callback as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may `Condition` the function pattern such that it matches for a parameter of `Head` `Function` or on the `DownValues` of the symbol when they have the pattern of that matches a *basic* function define by `SetDelayed`.

As pointed out in the OP comments there are many forms that a *function* can take and the solution below will not cover them all.  However, it may be enough to cover the cases within your particular project.

With

```
ClearAll[g]
g[func_, a_, b_] /; 
  MatchQ[func, _Function] \[Or] 
   Length@Cases[DownValues[func][[All, 1]], \[FormalP] : HoldPattern[_[_Pattern .., ___]] :> 
       Hold@\[FormalP], 2] > 0 :=
 func[a + b]
```

and

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 1
```

Then

```
g[f, 1, 2]
```

> ```
> 8
> ```

```
g[# + 1 &, 1, 2]
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

```
g[y, 1, 2]
```

> ```
> g[y, 1, 2]
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I removed the underscore after `func` in `MatchQ[func_,_Function]`. With the solution as written, I got an error about putting the pattern `function` on the right of a conditional. Also, you use `foo_` in the argument list but `func` in the rest of the example; I presume that's just an oversight.

Comment: @ibeatty Sorry, hasty change of variables as I realised you used `func` in your question and I had used `foo` in my notebook.  Fixed.

Comment: @ibeatty Before you use this, consider things like `InterpolatingFunction`, `CompiledFunction`, the result of a `LinearModelFit`, functions defined with `SubValues`, e.g. `add[x_][y_] := y+x`, `increment = add[1]`, and *countless* other examples.