# Is there something like a function pattern test?

Tags: argument-patterns

Is there something like a function pattern test?

```
function[x_?FunctionQ]:=Module[{},]
```

In order that Mathematica can tell if the argument is a function or a parameter?

Comment: Just use `Function` or `Symbol`.

Comment: The problem is that 'function' is not very well defined in MMA, you could start with e.g.: `_Function | (s_Symbol /; Length[DownValues[s]] > 0)`

Comment: @Xminer fyi `x : Except[ _Symbol]` but `Sin` is a function isn't it?

Comment: @Xminer it is all about what OP wants, I'd say `Sin` is function while `Sin[x]` is a function call.

Comment: @Kuba Ah,I see.

Comment: I agree with @Kuba that the concept of a function is ill-defined. What I have done in the past is to leave the checking for the body of the module: each time the function is actually used, make sure that the result is a number, and if it isn't, then issue an error message or even return the whole call unevaluated, as shown in the documentation of [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) under "Details". In this way, all the myriad forms of specifying a function are covered.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147942/wl-terminology-evaluate-call-invoke-use-etc

Comment: Shadowry's answer on the question Alan quoted seams very much related to what I asked.