# Is the Mathematica Language a LISP?

Tags: lisp

The syntax of the language is centered around M-expressions, which is equivalent to LISP's s-expression.

While the evaluator behaves differently than many LISPs , mainly being term rewrite with pattern matching, with a global rule base, I believe both are Turing complete, and furthermore close enough to easily be extended so each can mutate to the other. A big swath of Scheme follows the substitution model anyway so they are very close indeed.

But are they close enough ? Can Mathematica be considered a LISP , albeit with its own peculiar evaluator.

Another way of stating this question is : What is the essence of a LISP ? what makes a language based of an abstract syntax tree with an evaluator a LISP or not ?

Comment: Have you seen [Why did the Mathematica Language choose term rewriting instead of the Lambda Calculus as its basis?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119933/27951)

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, and it did not satisfy me, because you CAN do lambda calculus in Mathematica.

Comment: I think they feel close enough. One other difference, however, is that M- is an infinite loop evaluator, while LISPs are mostly single step evaluators. It's probably simpler to make a single step evaluator behave like an infinite loop evaluator then the other way around.